# 404 in Routes.php with laravel 5

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a route that I have recently change to:

```
Route::get('/tournaments/{{tournamentId}}/invite/{token}', 'InviteController@register');
```

When I try to access it with

```
http://laravel.dev:8000/tournaments/1/invite/ad5a5sd
```

I get a 404...

All my others routes work fine...

Any idea what could be the problem??

Comment: You shouldn't be using double curly braces.

Comment: uyyy My Bad! Please post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a small error (easy to overlook), but you shouldn't be using double curly braces. `{{tournamentId}}` should be `{tournamentId}` so the route should be:

```
Route::get('/tournaments/{tournamentId}/invite/{token}', 'InviteController@register');
```